# scipy.optimize.linprog not able to find solution

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming

I am trying to check if data is linearly separable or not. I am using the equations mentioned at this [link](https://www.joyofdata.de/blog/testing-linear-separability-linear-programming-r-glpk/) for the purpose. I am using the linprg function of the Scipy package in python. The sizes of arrays are as follows:

> A = [12137810,11]
>   A1 = [12137,11]
>   b = 12137
>   c = 11

Here is the code that I am using:

```
try:
        import os
        import random
        import traceback
        import numpy as np
        import scipy.io as sio
        from scipy.optimize import linprog
        os.system('cls')
        dicA  = sio.loadmat('A.mat')
        A = dicA.get('A')
        lengthA = int(len(A)/1000)
        aRange = range(0,lengthA)
        selectedIndexes = random.sample(aRange,lengthA)
        A1 = A[selectedIndexes]
        print('a = [',len(A),',',len(A[0]),']')
        print('a1 = [',len(A1),',',len(A1[0]),']')
        del A
        b = -1*np.ones(len(A1),np.int64)
        c = np.zeros(11,np.int64)
        print('c = ',len(c))
        print('b =',len(b))
        del dicA
        res = linprog(c, A_ub=A1, b_ub=b, bounds=(None,None),options={"disp": True,"maxiter": 25000})
        print(res)
except:
        print('exception')
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        print(tb)
finally:

        print('reached finally')
```

Here is the output that I am getting:

```
Iteration limit reached.
fun: -0.0  message: 'Iteration limit reached.'
nit: 25000   status: 1  success: False
x: nan reached finally
```

So, even after 2500 iteration, it was not able to find a solution, nor did it say that solution does not exist.So, does that mean solution does not exist? Or should I increase the iteration limit, if so then by how much?

Comment: In the book "Numerical Optimization" by Nocedal and Wright, the authors claim "the [simplex] method generally requires at most 2m to 3m iterations, where m is the row dimension of the constraint matrix".  (That's a comment about typical behavior, not the worst case.)  You have over 12000 constraints, so requiring more than 25000 iterations is not unexpected.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Is there any other faster python library?

Comment: I don't have any better recommendations than what [google suggests](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+linear+programming&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).  Version 1.0.0 of scipy will have an implementation of an interior point method, but that is not released yet.

Comment: You can use any of the (opens-source) alternatives: clp/cbc, glpk, lp_solve (all have simplex-based solvers) or cvxopt (IPM-based solver). For all python wrappers exist, some are easier to use than others. The former is probably the best solver, but with the worst docs.

Comment: @sascha The status code did change and the result was "Optimization failed. Unable to find a feasible starting point." . So, does that mean data is not linearly separable.

Comment: Hmm, either your problem has no solution or it's a bug / numerical-problem of linprog. For all commercial solvers i would treat this as *infeasible certificate* (they probably are more careful generating these certificates and formulation would look different), but with linprog i'm careful as there are some open issues not beeing worked on (e.g. unable to find feasible starting point for feasible problem). Sorry. **Remark:** If your task is about deciding if some LP is feasible or not, don't use IPM methods, at least not the ones without self-homogeneous embedding (cvxopt does it).

Comment: @sascha Thanks for the help, I will try some other library, just to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you trust the solver (= quality of implementation), increase iteration-limit until some other exit-status occurs.

A good implementation will always end in finite time, meaning: **the exit-status will change at some iteration-size**. There will be a solution or some certificate for unboundedness or infeasibility.

**Edit:** Above consequences are limited to implementations of the simplex-method (quality implementation)! [Interior-point methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_point_method) behave differently and do not have an underlying theory in general to provide these certificates robustly (theory in general assumes that the problem is feasible), the exception beeing the ones using a homogeneous self-dual embedding ([An O(√nL)-Iteration Homogeneous and Self-Dual Linear Programming Algorithm](http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/moor.19.1.53?journalCode=moor)).

The Simplex-algorithm in general is known to use quite a lot of iterations in general (at least compared to Interior-point methods; i'm not judging about your example).